# Redis - getting 5 elements at a time from a sorted set

Tags: redis, sortedset

I have a sorted set that keeps growing in real time and it contains some ID's which I want to retrieve 5 at a time in reverse order of rank. This is basically to implement pagination. These ID's are keys to a Hashmap. Is there any way to get 5 elements at a time efficiently using redis ZSet operations?

For example, in the Sorted Set below, let's say I want to get 5 elements before "572c7d87e53156245a3fd167", how could I do that given that new ID's could keep getting added after my last element in run time? The expected result should give me the ID's 572c7c58e53156245a3fd166, 572c7ad2e53156245a3fd165, 572c746e1eeba6b059b08f1b, 572c74531eeba6b059b08f1a, and 572c6fc9612ad65757cca4f9.

```
 1) "572b58c0dd319a1a4703eba8"
 2) "1462429760.8629999"
 3) "572c697e612ad65757cca4f7"
 4) "1462499582.6889999"
 5) "572c6a8e612ad65757cca4f8"
 6) "1462499854.056"
 7) "572c6fc9612ad65757cca4f9"
 8) "1462501193.927"
 9) "572c74531eeba6b059b08f1a"
10) "1462502355.5250001"
11) "572c746e1eeba6b059b08f1b"
12) "1462502382.313"
13) "572c7ad2e53156245a3fd165"
14) "1462504018.325"
15) "572c7c58e53156245a3fd166"
16) "1462504408.1370001"
17) "572c7d87e53156245a3fd167"
18) "1462504711.4200001"
19) "572c7da3e53156245a3fd168"
20) "1462504739.352"
```

Comment: Have you looked at zrevrange?

Comment: thanks @ItamarHaber. Yes I looked at it. The main challenge in my case is because of the values of the scores. Hence if I want last N values, it's hard to set a lower bound for the score to provide a range.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to look at `ZRANGEBYLEX` or `ZRANGEBYSCORE` and use the offset/count.

However what I usually do for pagination is create a new list (kind of a snapshot of the original list), that doesn't change dynamically, and load data from there. That way it doesn't feel like chasing a moving target. I just set a TTL to it and forget about it.

Comment: thanks. that's an interesting way of doing this. Did this work well for you even at scale? Seems like if there are too many users, then one would have many such lists around.

Comment: My TTL is 20mins and I limit the list to 1000 keys. Each key is around 32bytes. So I have about 32KB per user. This means that with 320MB I can support 10000 "concurrent" users. It is more than enough for my website.